# What are points of disagreement between Gabriel Marcel and Michael Polanyi?

Tags: gabriel-marcel, polanyi

I see similarities between Gabriel Marcel's distinction between problem and mystery and Michael Polanyi's distinction between explicit and tacit knowledge. However, I suspect that similarity may be only on the surface.

Is there any paper that describes their differences? Finding difference may help clarify what each is trying to say.

One difference I suspect is that Polanyi may have a more positive view of explicit knowledge than Marcel does of the problem, but on that I might be mistaken.

Hence the question: *What are points of disagreement between Gabriel Marcel and Michael Polanyi?*

Comment: I am tempted to say that they are from parallel (or different) philosophical universes;  somebody might have noticed a resemblance but I dont imagine a paper about their differences. Explicit/tacit knowledge would fit AI interests, while Marcel's problem/mystery is basically a defense for  philosophy-cum-religion developments.  Perhaps Michel Meyer's "Problematologie"  could provide some insights for comparisons.

Comment: Many authors note this similarity, see e.g. [Poteat, The Primacy of Persons and the Language of Culture, p.49](https://books.google.com/books?id=OWd94S9vGS0C&source=gbs_navlinks_s), but I have not seen any detailed comparisons between the two.